# Mongoose populate is not a function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I want the post's creator to be a user Schema. So i have 2 Schema

post.js

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema= mongoose.Schema;

const postSchema= new Schema({
    body:{ type: String, required:true, validate:bodyValidators},
    createdBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'User'}, // this one
    to: {type:String, default:null },
    createdAt: { type:Date, default:Date.now()},
    likes: { type:Number,default:0},
    likedBy: { type:Array},
    dislikes: { type:Number, default:0},
    dislikedBy: { type:Array},
    comments: [
        {
            comment: { type: String, validate: commentValidators},
            commentator: { type: String}
        }
    ]
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('Post',postSchema);
```

user.js

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema= mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema=new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true, validate: emailValidators},
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true, validate: usernameValidators},
    password: { type: String, required: true,validate: passwordValidators},
    bio: { type:String,default:null},
    location: {type:String, default:null},
    gender: {type:String,default:null},
    birthday: { type:Date,default:null},
    img: { type:String, default:'Bloggy/uploads/profile/avatar.jpeg'}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

When a user creates a new post, I save his _id into a new post object

```
const post= new Post({
        body: req.body.body,
        createdBy:user._id,
        createdAt:Date.now()
});
```

And when i want to recover all posts with their assigned author

```
router.get('/allPosts',(req,res)=>{
        Post.find().populate('createdBy').exec((err,posts)=>{
            if(err){
                res.json({success:false,message:err});
            }
            else{
                if (!posts) {
                    res.json({success:false,message:"No posts found"});
                }
                else{
                    res.json({success:true,posts:posts});
                }
            }
        }).sort({'_id':-1}); // the latest comes first
    });
```

It doesn't work though i've followed [the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). The error i get is `TypeError: Post.find(...).populate(...).exec(...).sort is not a function`
What am I doing wrong ? Am I missing something ? Maybe the fact that both models are not in the same file ?

Comment: When you create your new post, do you then call post.save()?

Comment: @SteveHolgado yes

Comment: And what is the result of your **Post.find().populate('createdBy').exec()** call? Do you get the documents but with the **createdBy** field not populated? ...or do you get no returned documents?

Comment: I get `TypeError: Post.find(...).populate(...).exec(...).sort is not a function`

Comment: Try sort before exec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.exec()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) returns a Promise and has no method called `.sort()`.

`.sort()` goes before `.exec()` as in `Post.find(...).populate(...).sort(...).exec(...)`

Look at 3rd example in the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

Answer (score 7):

Remove execPopulate() it might work. It worked for me.

Comment: Their code doesn't even reference `execPopulate()`, so it's unclear how removing it is going to solve their problem.